# Google App engine dosen't read the cloudbuild.yaml file

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I have a google App engine app taking more than 10min to deploy, so I used `gcloud config set app/cloud_build_timeout 1200` but it dosen't seams to work since i have `ERROR: (gcloud.app.deploy) Error Response: [4] Cloud build did not succeed within 10m.` But then I saw that I might require a cloudbuild.yaml file in my folder therfore I have only this in my cloudbuild.yaml :

```
steps: 
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/gcloud' 
args: ['app', 'deploy', '[/app.yaml]'] 
timeout: '1600s'
```

but again I have the same error. Do I do something bad with my cloudbuild file ? or maybe I have to set up it with the GCP gui ?

[Here is my project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eQChc.png)

Comment: Are you sure that your app.yaml file is at the root directory `/`? And not in `/workspace/app.yaml`?

Comment: Yes I added my folder structure to my question

Comment: Great, so, my comment is different: Can you try with `/workspace/app.yaml` and tell me if it's better?

Comment: How do I specify to gcp, when I deploy, to use the app.yaml for the parent folder ?

Comment: In your Cloudbuild.yaml file, change just the reference of the app.yaml file!

Comment: it still dosen't work... I always have this "Délai avant expiration
10 min" when I go to cloud builds logs

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide a properly indented `cloudbuild.yaml` file?

I can't tell if your `timeout` property applies to the specific step or the whole build process.

Build steps are not time-limited by default. *The whole build process* is limited to 10 minutes.

In order to exeed the 10 minutes mark you need to specify the `timeout` property of the whole build process, [as explained here](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/build-config-file-schema#timeout_2).